# VSCODE gdb on windows show empty file on debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, msys2, win64

I try to setup helloworld project with vscode and gdb for cpp.

I uses msys2.

It all sets just fine, project compiles and runs, but i have problem with debugging it.

Here my launch.json

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
  {
    "name": "(gdb) Launch",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/helloworld.exe",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": true,
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": true,
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "miDebuggerPath": "C:/msys64/usr/bin/gdb.exe",
    "setupCommands": [
      {
        "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
        "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
        "ignoreFailures": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

}

and my demo project

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code!"};

    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

}
```

But when i run debug, instead source file it show just empty file, i figure out that new file created in

C:\c\Users\user\projects\helloworld\

so there a problem with path there.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use wrong gdb.

You need install other version of gdb:

```
 pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb
```

and use it

```
"miDebuggerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe",
```